# Do borrowing costs go down as a currency depreciates?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, currency, bonds, currency-exchange

I was watching a video (https://youtu.be/2CVOfzuqoY4) and got very confused by the following sentence at 1:18:

"Usually when an established currency depreciates in value, borrowing costs in that country go down because it makes bonds issued in that currency cheaper".

What is he trying to say here? That current british bond prices are going higher(because borrowing cost is going lower) as the GBP devalues? Or that buying British Bonds is much more favorable now for people who are exchanging from, say USD for example, because they can now buy more GBP for a given dollar and therefore buy british bonds cheaper?

He then goes on to say the reverse occured "As the pound decreased the cost of borrowing increased" without explaining why.

I understand how bonds work. As interest rates(borrowing costs) rise, the price of current bonds on the market decrease(while the yield rises) and vice versa.

I just didn't understand why it's "usual" that as a currency devalues the borrowing costs decrease. I'd have always thought that a devalued currency would lead to raising interest rates which would mean borrowing costs have increased not decreased...

Comment: Why do you even care what a bunch of recent graduates promulgates on a channel called *too long didn't read" with producers called SPDARKLORD and ULTRACZAR.

Comment: @Alex It's not that I care. I'm just verifying and trying to make sense of what's being said in the video with my own knowledge of finance and economics.